# Why do Horses Drown?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

After accidentally killing 2 of my 3 horses from drowning I began to brighten up. Why are they drowning? Usually mobs will jump up in the water and that helps protect them. Do horses drown because they are weighed down by the saddle?

Comment: I've seen evidence that it might be due to falling water blocks, but can't verify this myself.

Comment: Because they can't breathe water. BOOM, 15 rep please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are weighted by the rider. It's hard to say why they don't always swim up - they just don't, probably a bug, but maybe it was just written that way - who knows?

Anyway, don't go swimming on the horseback. Have a lead with you, and as you approach a body of water, dismount, leash your horse and swim across pulling it after you.

Edit: [It's a bug](https://mojang.atlassian.net/browse/MC-13788).

Comment: You automatically get off the horse in 3 deep water though...

Comment: Problem i was leading one of the horses that died and he still wouldn't swim

Comment: @MBraedley: Yes, but by then the horse is usually three blocks deep under water and drowning, and leashing it poses a certain challenge. Doing that on the shore is far safer.

Comment: @SF. ...but only if the water is flowing.  Horses will swim up source blocks, but they get pulled under by falling water.

Comment: Also, that bug you linked to was fixed a while ago.

Comment: @MBradley: I assure you it was an inert "river" across the desert, nothing was flowing or pulling anything. After forced dismounting the horse just stayed some five blocks deep and failed to surface.

Comment: @SF. Yes, I don't doubt that - if you were playing in a snapshot.  But like I said, the bug that you're describing was fixed before release.

Comment: @MBraedley: Official, 1.6.1. I was very enthusiastic about the Horse Update and went on search for horses ASAP. Then my first horse drowned on the way back home. I managed to rescue another using the leash.